# Is the identity functor a kind of free object?

Tags: category-theory, haskell

My understanding of free objects is: Free functors, free applicatives, free monads, free monoids, &c, give you more structure "for free", i.e. in general, or for all *some thing with less structure, you can have more for free*. For example, the free monad give you a monad instance for any type with a functor instance, even without its own native monad instance.

The [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) functor gives you a functor (and applicative, and monad) instance for any type. Therefore it seems to me to be a sort of free structure. Am I write about this, or am I confusing myself by my vague definition of free objects?